# file_put_content doesn't evaulate newlines from file_get_content

Tags: php, file, fwrite

I have 2 php files named `index.php` and `detail.php`.

My porblem is that even thought this script writes to the text file correctly but when it writes content of `detail.php` it writes `\n` instead of the newline.

Expected Output:

```
A
B
C
D
```

I get:

```
A
B
C\nD
```

Here is the code for the files:
`index.php`

```
<?php

$filename= 'logs/'.$d.'a.txt';
$extra=file_get_contents("detail.php");
$somecontent = "A\nB\n".$extra;

$handle = fopen($filename, 'a');
fwrite($handle, $somecontent);
fclose($handle);

?>
```

`detail.php`

```
<?php

echo 'C\nD';

?>
```

The result of `file_get_contents` is directly written as if copy-pasted, the `\n` chracter is not considered as newline.

What i have tried:

`detail.php`

=>`echo 'C\r\nD'`

=>`echo 'C\\nD';`

=>`echo 'C\\r\\nD';`

=>`echo 'C'.PHP_EOL.'D';`

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: [Difference between single quotes and double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php). Since everybody's saying use single quotes but nobody told you why you should use single quotes specifically.

Comment: Hi, try this code `<?php

echo "C<br>D";

?>`

Answer (score 2):

To use *\n* *\r\n* etc in strings you have to put them in doublequotes instead of single eg **echo "C\r\nD";**

Answer (score 0):

Remove the singe quote marks and take double ones. `'` -> `"`